# Install Chrome US-Version outside of US for native OK Google

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I read that the "Ok Google" Hands-Free-Hotword for Chrome is currently only available for US Chrome Users (I'm from Austria). I know that a plugin exists but I either need a valid *.crx Version of it or the native Version inside Chrome for what I want to do. Any ideas?

[German Article](http://stadt-bremerhaven.de/google-chrome-suchen-per-hotword-wird-zum-standard-sofern-von-euch-aktiviert/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/3542118?hl=en) doesn't say about "Okay Google" hotword detection only working for US users.

Did you follow the instructions to enable "Okay Google" hotword detection?

Make sure you are on [`google.com/ncr`](http://google.com/ncr) (No Country Redirect) and not on any of its country specific homepages.

The text under "Availability" states: It only works if the browser language is set to US-English.

Comment: I knew about google.com/ncr but I didn't know the thing written bellow Availability of your link. I added the fact that the browser needs to be set to US-English to your answer. I didn't test it because I got it working with the plugin meanwhile too.